# Ruby array questions

Tags: ruby

```
def fib_up_to(max)

  i1, i2 = 2, 1

  while i1 <= max
    yield i1
    i1 ,i2 = i2, i1 + i2
  end
end

fib_up_to(10) { |f| print f, " "}
```

This prints out - `2 1 3 4 7`

but when I change it to

```
def fib_up_to(max)

  i1, i2 = 2, 1

  while i1 <= max
    yield i1
    i1 = i2 
    i2 = i1 + i2
  end
end

fib_up_to(10) { |f| print f, " "}
```

It is giving me `2 4 2 4 8`

I am confused how is it any different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first assignment doesn't change values to affect the second assignment with this statement  i1 ,i2 = i2, i1+i2

the second way does as shown below

```
 irb(main):012:0> i1, i2 = 2,1
=> [2, 1]
irb(main):015:0> i1 ,i2 = i2, i1+i2
=> [1, 3]
irb(main):016:0> i1
=> 1
irb(main):017:0> i2
=> 3


irb(main):023:0> i1, i2 = 2,1
=> [2, 1]
irb(main):024:0>     i1 = i2
=> 1
irb(main):025:0>     i2 = i1+i2
=> 2
irb(main):026:0> i1
=> 1
irb(main):027:0> i2
=> 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Nvm I found the answer. For those who are interested it goes like this:
First method

I1  I2

2   1 #First row

1   3 # I2 = I1+I2 (both of 1st row)

Second method:

I1   I2

2    1

1    2 #because I2 = I1(2nd row) + I2 (first row)